# youtube inbox problem

Tags: iphone, youtube, gdata

I'm trying to programmatically (using gdata api) retrieve incoming messages from youtube account.

My request:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/my_nick/inbox"];

NSMutableURLRequest *inboxRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

NSString *authStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"GoogleLogin auth=%@", authMarker];

[inboxRequest setValue:authStr forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
[inboxRequest addValue:@"Content-Type" forHTTPHeaderField:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"];
[inboxRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

NSHTTPURLResponse *response = NULL;

NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:inboxRequest returningResponse:&response error:nil];

NSString *responseDataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

NSLog(@"\n%@\n", responseDataString);
NSLog(@"\n%@\n", [inboxRequest ]);
```

return feed without entries... (although I can see incoming messages on the site)

here response from nslog:
`<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><feed xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:openSearch='http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/'><id>http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/thisistestnick/inbox</id><updated>2011-06-16T14:45:00.475Z</updated><category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind' term='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#videoMessage'/><title type='text'>Inbox of thisistestnick</title><logo>http://www.youtube.com/img/pic_youtubelogo_123x63.gif</logo><link rel='alternate' type='text/html' href='http://www.youtube.com/my_messages?folder=inbox&amp;filter=videos'/><link rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#feed' type='application/atom+xml' href='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/thisistestnick/inbox'/><link rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#batch' type='application/atom+xml' href='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/thisistestnick/inbox/batch'/><link rel='self' type='application/atom+xml' href='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/thisistestnick/inbox?start-index=1&amp;max-results=25'/><author><name>thisistestnick</name><uri>http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/thisistestnick</uri></author><generator version='2.0' uri='http://gdata.youtube.com/'>YouTube data API</generator><openSearch:totalResults>0</openSearch:totalResults><openSearch:startIndex>1</openSearch:startIndex><openSearch:itemsPerPage>25</openSearch:itemsPerPage></feed>`

what is wrong? pls help.

Comment: my question is too simple or v.v.?

Answer (score 0):

Why cant you use,  [gdata-objectivec](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/) lib api's rather doing your own parsing ? I havent tried retrieving 'inbox' but was fairly successful in getting the info i want. Advantages of using it are:

a) You get the info in native formats (Strings and Dictionaries), lib does the job of parsing feeds for you.
b) mainly, there wont be any parsing/api understanding errors (which i suppose is the reason for your problem).