# YouTube inbox do not work

Tags: iphone, objective-c, youtube-api, gdata

Anybody know how to get inbox from youtube account?
My request ([in question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6374202/youtube-inbox-problem)) and [Interactive YouTube API Demo Beta](http://gdata.youtube.com/demo/index.html) returning "totalResults=0"...

Answer (score 2):

All requests are working! but only with messages which contain video.

Comment: I'm currently having the same problem, but I can't even see video messages. YouTube always returns an empty list for me.